# PowerShell: force password change at the next logon for multiple users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

I'm new to PowerShell and am still learning the ropes. I want to create a script for work that I can force a change at the next logon for many users.

I have this:

`Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$True -path 'C:\users\mohahigg\desktop\userpassword.txt' (ConvertTo-SecureString 'password2022' -AsPlainText -Force)`

I know it's not the best, but what went wrong (in detail), and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is in the `userpassword.txt` file? Is it a list of users you want to force password change at next logon? What is the purpose of `(ConvertTo-SecureString 'password2022' -AsPlainText -Force)`? Do you also want to change the password for all the users?

Comment: it is there login name, and I want that to be there default password to use before they change it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to extract the username from the text file. You've chosen an odd way of doing it. If it's just one user, you could simply write the name in the command instead of in a file. However, we will get the username and set it in the `$user` variable:

```
$user = Get-Content 'C:\users\mohahigg\desktop\userpassword.txt'
```

Next, we will reset the user's password.

- `-Path` is not a valid parameter for the `Set-ADAccountPassword` command
- `-ChangePasswordAtLogon` is also not a  valid parameter

See all parameters in the official documentation: *[Set-ADAccountPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps)*

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString 'password2022' -AsPlainText -Force) -Reset
```

Lastly, we will force the password change at the next logon, which is done in another command, *[Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser)*. See the official documentation for this: *[Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps)*.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Putting it all together:

```
$user = Get-Content 'C:\users\mohahigg\desktop\userpassword.txt'
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString 'password2022' -AsPlainText -Force) -Reset
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Comment: Hey Scott that really helps a lot. The script ran perfectly well.